# Why the arrow function that returns arrow function inside componentWillUnmount lifecycle is not removed by removeEventListener? (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, arrow-functions

I am currently working on React.js Class component.

I have added listener using addEventListener inside componentDidMount like below.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('copy', this.copyBlock('copy'));
    document.addEventListener('cut', this.copyBlock('cut'));
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('copy', this.copyBlock('copy'));
    document.removeEventListener('cut', this.copyBlock('cut'));
  }

  // This is the function that added by addEventListener.
  // As you can see, argument copyType is passed to copyBlock function and returns event object.
  copyBlock = (copyType: 'copy' | 'cut') => (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
    if (e.target !== document.body) {
      return;
    }
    const {
      type,
      libraryStore: { showUtilBlock },
    } = this.props;

    BlockUtil.copyBlock(e, copyType);
  };
```

However, here is the problem.

When the component is unmounted, the function is supposed to be removed. However, it is not.

But, When I changed **copyBlock** function like below, it works. it is removed.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('copy', this.copyBlock);
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('copy', this.copyBlock);
  }

  copyBlock = (e?: ClipboardEvent) => {
    if (e.target !== document.body) {
      return;
    }
    const {
      type,
      libraryStore: { showUtilBlock },
    } = this.props;

   BlockUtil.copyBlock(e, 'copy');
  };
```

What is the difference? Why eventListener does not work on the arrow function that returns function?

Comment: you are invoking function directly, you can use it like that:
document.addEventListener('copy', () => this.copyBlock('copy'));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it will create a new event handler every time when you call `this.copyBlock()`. Each of them has a different pointer. The event handler that passed in `removeEventListener()` should be the same as the event handler passed in `addEventListener()`.(Same pointer)

Try this:

```
constructor() {
  this.copy = this.copyBlock('copy');
  this.cut = this.copyBlock('cut');
}

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('copy', this.copy);
  document.addEventListener('cut', this.cut);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('copy', this.copy);
  document.removeEventListener('cut', this.cut);
}
```